# Diferencias entre "ca" y "porque"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, significado, historia, conjunciones

En muchos textos escritos en los primeros siglos del español (siglos XVII en adelante) aparece *ca* usado como conjunción causal, a la que la RAE le otorga el siguiente significado:

> **[ca](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6MvUeqe)**
>
> Del lat. *quia*.
>
> 1. conj. causal. desus. **porque**.

El hecho de que signifique "porque" pero esté en desuso me llevó a pensar en un principio que "porque" fue algo que apareció más tarde y que acabó desplazando a "ca", pero no es así. Ya desde el mencionado siglo XVII aparecen ambas en textos. Véanse los siguientes ejemplos tomados del Poema de Mio Cid (c. 1140):

> *Grande duelo avién las yentes cristianas,
>
>   ascóndense de mio Cid, **ca** no l'osan dezir nada.*
>
> ---
>
> *Plogo a mio Cid, **porque** creció en la yantar,
>
>   plogo a los otros omnes, todos cuantos con él están.*

Así pues, ¿existía alguna sutil diferencia entre "ca" y "porque" que hiciera que cada una se usara en contextos o situaciones diferentes? Y por ir un poco más allá, ¿hubo alguna causa que hiciera que "ca" desapareciera del uso?

Comment: Que sepa yo, pues no. Por lo menos, nunca lo he interpretado de otra forma, ni notado diferencia en su uso.

Comment: @guifa al buscar en el CORDE me di cuenta de que (aunque no es el caso de los ejemplos que expongo) "porque" solía ir sin signo de puntuación previo, mientras que "ca" solía ir precedido de una coma, punto y coma o similar, como iniciando una frase nueva más que continuando la anterior. ¿Podría ser? En todo caso, amplío la pregunta para ver si así le doy un poco más de juego.

Comment: ¿Será por su parecido con el francés _car_ de mismo significado? Ya hemos divagado en alguna ocasión sobre la tendencia a _afrancesarse_ en el siglo XVIII.

Comment: @fedorqui precisamente en el siglo XVIII la voz "ca" ya estaba marcada como de uso antiguo.

Comment: Aquí hay una explicación para el francés, donde hay dos formas similares y ambas siguen en uso. En ese caso se confirma lo que dices de la puntuación http://correspo.ccdmd.qc.ca/index.php/document/de-nouvelles-grammaires/car-et-parce-que/

Comment: @rsanchez Parece que en el francés *car* se usa algo como el *pues* causal del castellano.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Parece que la conjunción "ca" era muy versátil y podía asumir distintas funciones, lo que significaría su principal diferencia con "porque".

Como se menciona en la fuente su frecuencia de uso en el Poema del Mio Cid es mucho mayor que la de "porque" (42,16% vs 8,52%). Dentro de las funciones que puede asumir "ca" se mencionan la función casual (como el caso de "por", "porque", "puesto que"), la completiva (como el caso de "que", "si") y la comparativa (caso similar a "como", "así como") y adversativa (como lo son "pero", "mas", "aunque"); teniendo incluso más funciones otras lenguas romances.

En [esta otra fuente](https://www.um.es/tonosdigital/znum21/secciones/estudios-22-causales.htm%20secci%C3%B3n:%20III.1.2%20Desplazamientos%20del%20valor%20causal%20%20de%20ca) se le dan incluso otros significados, equivaliendo a veces a "y", "en verdad" y "por ello".

Con respecto a la pregunta de qué causó la desaparición de "ca" como conjunción, me adhiero a la opinión de @CarlosAlejo al pensar que se debió precisamente a su versatilidad. En la misma fuente citada se menciona algo, que si bien no es una respuesta literal a la pregunta, si podría ser tomada como una pista:

> " *...los pocos casos en que ca se emplea como suborninante, se deben probablemente a un proceso de atenuación o desgaste. El estudio diacrónico, no obstante, nos demostrará que la evolución es justamente en sentido contrario: el frecuente uso acabará debilitando su significado ordinario, pasando a introducir, no sólo coordinadas o explicativas casuales, sino también adversativas, copulativas, ilativas, etc.*"

Fuente adicional:

- [*Las conjunciones de causa en castellano medieval: origen, evolución y otros usos*](https://books.google.com.co/books?id=TAfEKZTp6RYC&dq=citar%20Las%20conjunciones%20de%20causa%20en%20castellano%20medieval:%20origen,%20evoluci%C3%B3n%20y%20otros%20usos&hl=es&source=gbs_navlinks_s), Manuel Mosteiro Louzao, 1999.

Comment: Entiendo entonces que "porque" no era más que uno de los posibles significados de "ca", que era mucho más versátil. ¿Se podría decir que esta versatilidad fue la que acabó haciéndola desaparecer en favor de palabras más especializadas?

Comment: @CarlosAlejo, aunque es especulación, y bajo riesgo de sacar la frase un poco de contexto, llego a tu misma conclusión luego de leer esta frase de la fuente que está marcada en la respuesta como "Fuente adicional":   ...los pocos casos en que ca se emplea como subordinante, se deben probablemente a un proceso de atenuación o desgaste. El estudio diacrónico ... nos demostrará que la evolución es justamente en sentido contrario: el frecuente uso acabará debilitando su significado ordinario, pasando a introducir, no sólo coordinadas o explicativas casuales, sino también adversativas...

Comment: Pues aunque sea especulación, puedes añadirla a la respuesta para así hacerla más completa. No sería la primera vez que se dan por válidas respuestas basadas en suposiciones de quien responde, si están hechas con criterio.